# Obtain this.index(this) in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I clicked on that I get a tag index

1. My Html Code

   ```
   <html>
           <head>
           <title>nss plugin</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="nss.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
           </head>
           <body>
             <a href="../img/ib1.jpg" rel="group"class="asd"><img src="../img/is1.jpg"/></a>
             <a href="../img/ib2.jpg" rel="group"class="asd"><img src="../img/is2.jpg"/></a>
             <a href="../img/ib3.jpg" rel="group"class="asd"><img src="../img/is3.jpg"/></a>
             <a href="../img/ib4.jpg" rel="group"class="asd"><img src="../img/is4.jpg"/></a>

           </body>
   </html>
   ```

2 . My jquery plugin code.

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.nss = function( ) {

        var thisindx = this.index(this);
        console.log(thisindx);

          return this;

    };

}( jQuery ))
```

3.my javascript code

```
$(function(){
 $('a[rel="group"]').click(function(){
  $('a[rel="group"]').nss();
 })
});
```

Why thisindx value is equal to 0

How can a person get the actual value

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need a plugin, you can just do :

```
$(function(){
    $('a[rel="group"]').on('click', function(){
        $('a[rel="group"]').index(this);
    });
});
```

to get the current elements index withing the group.

**EDIT:**

inside a plugin you get the collection, and iterate over it with `return this.each`, so using each individual iteration and the collection, you can get the elements index in the set of elements in the selector like so:

```
$.fn.nss = function( ) {
    var elems = this

    return elems.each(function() {
        // all plugin code for multiple elements should normally go in a loop
        // like this one to perform the same actions on every element

        var thisindx = elems.index(this);
        console.log(thisindx);
    });
};
```

Comment: I'created this plugin , .nss() is Slideshow plug in.  https://github.com/MOHS3N/NSS/tree/master/nss%20plugin

Comment: I have problems in sending index() to this plug in

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var thisindx = this.index();
```

Or from the click event you can directly get the index value like

```
$(function(){
      $('a[rel="group"]').on('click',function(){
             $('a[rel="group"]').index();
             //Better use like
             $(this).index(); //or this.index();
      });
});
```